# Visual Studio Extension - Test Discoverer not listed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx

I have a Visual Studio Extension, that is shipped as VSIX. Part of this VSIX is a test runner implementation.

I have implemented an `ITestContainerDiscoverer`, `ITestDiscoverer` and and `ITestContainer`.

When I use it on VS 2013 Ultimate, it works fine. I can even verify that the test runner is recognized by running:

```
vstest.console /ListDiscoverers /UseVsixExtensions:true
```

The same VSIX when installed on VS 2013 Premium or Community Edition, does not discover tests. The `vstest.console` does not detect it either.

Any ideas?

PS - The code is [here](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-visualstudio/tree/master/Gauge.VisualStudio/TestRunner)

Comment: @ErikEJ - I am not so sure. The target framework is set to 4.5 which is installed in the host system.

Comment: Sorry, I meant:  Target Platform (x86 vs x86)

Comment: I have it set to "Any CPU", and this behaviour is on an x64 machine, haven't checked on x86 yet.